# My iPhone app works on the device, but not the simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

My app works okay on the device, but not the simulator. When I run it on the simulator I get no errors or anything. The app just dies a second after being launched. Does this really matter? Should I be concerned?

In fact, the only reason I wanted to run the simulator is to get an idea of how my app runs on the iPad (of which I don't physically own). What do we think?

Comment: I definitely wouldn't ignore it.

Comment: I think you it should display some sort of error message. It always does.

Comment: Look at the logging console - it should reveal the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no obvious logs, one thing you can do is to add some NSLog statements to each method.

I use these:

```
NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
```

Then, when I'm done debugging, I comment them out. That way I can see what was the last method the app entered before it stopped.

Answer (score 2):

You should always debug the reason that an app does not behave as expected, as this could be the underlying cause of a much more serious problem, such as a memory corruption that will cause the app to crash all the time for every customer after the moon phase changes just a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

The NSZombiesEnabled argument also helps track down bugs: http://iosdevelopertips.com/debugging/tracking-down-exc_bad_access-errors-with-nszombieenabled.html

Comment: This seems to be a great tool, but I tried it and it printed absolutely nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: There's really NOTHING in the debugger when you build&debug?

Comment: Um. I've made some progress and some things are printing to the console (even though the app still crashes). I don't see anything resembling the exceptions shown in the NSZombiesEnabled though. A shame because this seems like a great tool.

Comment: It might help if you posted some code here, and also posted your console log.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the simulator gets confused. Delete the content of ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications or thereabouts and try it again.